# How to prove that a polynomial of degree n is θ(x^n)

Tags: asymptotics

How can I prove that if $T(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ then $T(x) = \Theta(x^n)$.

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck? Without a *specific* question, this is just a duplicate of our reference question which explains general strategies of proving such claims.

Comment: Take care of adhereing to the exact definition of $\Theta$ you were given in class. Are functions with negative values allowed?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your question.

Comment: It is easy to show that $\dfrac{T(x)}{x^n}$ tends to a constant.

Answer (score 3):

Say $T(x) = a_n x^n + \dotsm + a_0$, then by the triangle inequality for $x \ge 1$:

$\begin{align}
   \lvert T(x) \rvert
     &\le \lvert a_n \rvert x^n + \lvert a_{n - 1} \rvert x^{n - 1}
            + \dotsm + \lvert a_0 \rvert \\
     &\le \lvert a_n \rvert x^n + \lvert a_{n - 1} \rvert x^n
            + \dotsm + \lvert a_0 \rvert x^n \\
     &= (\lvert a_n \rvert + \lvert a_{n - 1} \rvert + \dotsm + \lvert a_0 \rvert)
           x^n
\end{align}$

I'm sure you can take it from here. You'll have to figure out an appropriate lower bound to match.